# How to run anaconda python with "execute a process" in Pentaho(PDI) in windows?

Tags: python, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm going to run a python program by "execute a process" in pdi and on a specific anaconda environment.

This is my solution which didn't work:

[image]

```
run_on_win = "C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat & python" 

api_call = my python file

Remains fields are my parameters
```

How these commands, which run successfully on cmd, raise this error in PDI?

`Cannot run program "C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat & python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I created a .bat file with this content:

`conda activate churn & python %*`

the I assigned the path of that .bat file to run_on_win variable

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying the complete path of `python.exe`